# How to use a csv file in PHPUnit test

Tags: phpunit

I wrote a DataTest case following the example 4.5 of PHPUnit manual, the url is:
 http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers. 
But I came across with an error:

> *The data provider specified for DataTest::testAdd is invalid.
>
>   Data set #0 is invalid.*

I thought it maybe that I edit the data.csv file in a wrong way, then I used php function fputcsv() to create data.csv file, but it also didn't work, I want to know why, and how to resolve this problem. Thanks!

P. S.: the data in data.csv is:

> 0,0,0
>   0,1,1

---

The codes are show as follows:
DataTest.php

```
require 'CsvFileIterator.php';
class DataTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
public function provider()
    {
        return new CsvFileIterator('data.csv');
    }

    /**
    * @dataProvider provider
    */
    public function testAdd($a, $b, $c)
    {
         $this->assertEquals($c, $a + $b);
    }
}
```

CsvFileIterator.php

```
class CsvFileIterator implements Iterator
{
    protected $file;
    protected $key = 0;
protected $current;

public function __construct($file)
{
    $this->file = fopen($file, 'r');
}

public function __destruct()
{
    fclose($this->file);
}

public function rewind()
{
    rewind($this->file);
    $this->current = fgetcsv($this->file);
    $this->key = 0;
}

public function valid()
{
    return !feof($this->file);
}

public function key()
{
    return $this->key;
}

public function current()
{
    return $this->current;
}

public function next()
{
    $this->current = fgetcsv($this->file);
    $this->key++;
}
}
```

The data.csv file is create by function fputcsv():

```
$data = array(
array(0, 0, 0),
array(0, 1, 1)
);

$fp = fopen('data.csv', 'w');

foreach($data as $v)
{
fputcsv($fp, $v);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Please show the code of your data provider function. That is important to explain where you've made the error. Add it to your question by editing it (you can shorten filenames and other specific data that is not important to share to understand your problem).

Comment: @hakre, I have added the codes in my question, please help me to analyse and tell me why the error accurs, thanks!

Comment: Check in the constructor that your iterator can access the file. For instance you might need to pass it the full path (e.g. `__DIR__ . '/data.csv'`). Alternatively, use `true` as the [third parameter of fopen](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) to use the include path.

Answer (score 6):

Example :-)

```
/**
 * @dataProvider provider
 * @group csv
 */
public function testAdd($a, $b, $c)
{
    $this->assertEquals($c, $a + $b);
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function provider()
{
    $file = file_get_contents("/Volumes/htdocs/contacts.csv","r");
    foreach ( explode("\n", $file, -1) as $line )
    {
        $data[] = explode(',', $line);
    }
    return $data;
}

/*
 * CREATE TO CSV FILE DATAPROVIDER
 * don't create this file in your test case
 */
public function saveToCsv()
{
    $list = array(
        array(0,0,0),
        array(0,1,1)
    );

    $file = fopen("/Volumes/htdocs/contacts.csv","w");

    foreach ($list as $line)
    {
        fputcsv($file,$line);
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for you reply, I try it again and it works. But I still has a question, why can't I use `return new CsvFileIterator('csv file name');` in the function provider() just like the example 4.5 does. [link]http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers

Comment: @ZongshuLin Similar issue here. Check this [data.csv](https://github.com/rdok/phpunit.de/blob/02-writing-tests-for-phpunit/storage/data.csv), as well as my [approach](https://github.com/rdok/phpunit.de/blob/02-writing-tests-for-phpunit/tests/IteratorObjectDataProviderTest.php) when specifying the data.csv location.

Answer (score 1):

@ZongshuLin Similar issue here. Possible Solutions:

- Check this [data.csv](https://github.com/rdok/phpunit.de/blob/master/02-writing-tests-for-phpunit/storage/data.csv). Basically I had to add a row after the last line.
- You can also check my [approach on GitHub](https://github.com/rdok/phpunit.de/blob/ad2984fbc6976815fb9c4de6ba7a7c7a4f3664d5/02-writing-tests-for-phpunit/tests/providers/IteratorObjectDataProviderTest.php#L26) when specifying the data.csv location

> Use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant so the script may run on any OS--Windows uses backslashes while Linux slashes.

```
 /**
 * @return CsvFileIterator
 */
public function additionProvider()
{
    return new CsvFileIterator(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'storage/data.csv');
}
```

Comment: Your links are broken

Comment: Thanks for the review; patched.